# Populating listiview with data from mysql

Tags: javascript, java, android, mysql, listview

this is my baseadapter code

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
Activity activity;

public ListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>list ) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
super();
this.activity=(Activity)activity;
this.list=list;
}

public int getCount() {
return list.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return list.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
   TextView kd_matkul;
   TextView nm_matkul;
   TextView dosen;
   TextView sks;
 }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ViewHolder holder;
LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();
if (convertView == null)
{   
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_matkul, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.kd_matkul = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kd_matkul);
    holder.nm_matkul = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm_matkul);
    holder.dosen = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dosen);
    holder.sks = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sks);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
HashMap<String, String> item = list.get(position);
String kd_matkul = item.get("kd_matkul");
String nm_matkul = item.get("nm_matkul");
String dosen = item.get("nm_dosen");
String sks = item.get("sks");
holder.kd_matkul.setText(kd_matkul);
holder.nm_matkul.setText(nm_matkul);
holder.dosen.setText(dosen);
holder.sks.setText(sks);
return convertView;

}
}
```

And this is my main class code

```
public class Semester_1 extends Activity {

EditText txtNM;
EditText txtSKS;
EditText txtDSN;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> matkul;
ListView list;
HashMap<String, String> map;

String kode;

private static final String Matkul_Ganjil_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/m_krs/Matkul/getMatkul_sm1.php";
//private static final String AmbilMatkul_Ganjil_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/m_krs/Matkul/ambil_matkul.php";
//private static final String DetailMatkul_Ganjil_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/m_krs/Matkul/detail_matkul.php";
private static final String TAG_NMATKUL = "nm_matkul";
private static final String TAG_SKS = "sks";
private static final String TAG_NDSN = "nm_dosen";
private static final String TAG_KD = "kd_matkul";
private static final String TAG_SM1 = "matkul_sm1";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

JSONArray matkul5 = null;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.semester1);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    kode = i.getStringExtra(TAG_KD);
    matkul = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new LoadAllMatkul_Ganjil().execute();

}

public void simpanMatkul (View v){
    //new AmbilMatkul_Ganjil().execute();
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(this, KrsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void kembali (View v){       
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(this, KrsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


class LoadAllMatkul_Ganjil extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Semester_1.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Silahkan Tunggu...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {           
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Matkul_Ganjil_URL, "GET", params);

        Log.d("Semua Matkul: ", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                matkul5 = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SM1);
                for (int i = 0; i < matkul5.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matkul5.getJSONObject(i);


                    String nmmatkul = c.getString(TAG_NMATKUL);
                    String sks = c.getString(TAG_SKS);
                    String nmdosen = c.getString(TAG_NDSN);
                    String kdmatkul = c.getString(TAG_KD);


                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    map.put(TAG_KD, kdmatkul);
                    map.put(TAG_NMATKUL, nmmatkul);                        
                    map.put(TAG_NDSN, nmdosen);
                    map.put(TAG_SKS, sks);                       

                    matkul.add(map);
                }



            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Semester_1.this,
                        HomeMenu1.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Semester_1.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                ListAdapter listadapter = new ListAdapter(Semester_1.this, matkul);
                list.setAdapter(listadapter);
                listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

I got error with this code...

please tell me where is the poblem....

and if this problem is solve it...

I need more help...how I can get value from multiple checkbox ?

Sorry, this is the error message

```
10-26 18:50:50.701: I/Choreographer(1701): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-26 18:50:50.911: D/Semua Matkul:(1701): {"success":1,"matkul_sm1":[{"nm_matkul":"B. Inggris I","sks":"2","nm_dosen":"Koko Harianto, M.Kom","kd_matkul":"MTK-000001"},{"nm_matkul":"Kalkulus 1","sks":"3","nm_dosen":"Liya Astarila, M.Pd","kd_matkul":"MTK-000002"}]}
10-26 18:50:50.991: I/Choreographer(1701): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): MTK-000001
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): B. Inggris I
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): Koko Harianto, M.Kom
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): 2
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): MTK-000002
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): Kalkulus 1
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): Liya Astarila, M.Pd
10-26 18:50:51.171: I/System.out(1701): 3
10-26 18:50:51.181: D/AndroidRuntime(1701): Shutting down VM
10-26 18:50:51.181: W/dalvikvm(1701): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at apl.sisfo.semester.ganjil.ListAdapter.<init>(ListAdapter.java:27)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at apl.sisfo.semester.ganjil.Semester_1$LoadAllMatkul_Ganjil$1.run(Semester_1.java:145)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4673)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at apl.sisfo.semester.ganjil.Semester_1$LoadAllMatkul_Ganjil.onPostExecute(Semester_1.java:142)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at apl.sisfo.semester.ganjil.Semester_1$LoadAllMatkul_Ganjil.onPostExecute(Semester_1.java:1)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-26 18:50:51.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 18:50:53.852: I/Process(1701): Sending signal. PID: 1701 SIG: 9
```

Comment: One question at a time and ensure to explain it well. Simply posting/dumping code won't help. You haven't given a clue about the error and expect fellow SO members to magically solve your problem. Great. Good luck with that

Comment: can you please post the error message.

Comment: Sorry... 
I have already edit my querstion...
please help...